# VBScript Compilation Error, unable to resolve

Tags: command-line, vbscript, compiler-errors

So I'm trying to run a CMD prompt as a VBScript because I can't just drop this CMD Line.

```
Set cmdl = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmdl.Run "cmd.exe ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe""--app="https://app.powerbi.com/"""--kiosk""--fullscreen""--user-data-dir=c:/monitor1""
```

My dilemma is that every time I try and run this I get the following error:

> Script: Script.vbs
>   Line: 2
>   Char: 90
>   Error: Expected end of statement
>   Code: 800A0401
>   Source: Microsoft VBScript compilation error

I've tried putting in quotes, taking out quotes, moving spaces, etc. and this dang thing is driving me crazy. Does anyone see where my mistake may lie?

Comment: Type `cmd /?` to see where your are going wrong. CMD requires switches for anything other than interactive use.

Comment: What do you mean you're "trying to run a CMD prompt"? You don't need CMD to start Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Your command string is broken. In VBScript a string is defined by putting a character sequence between double quotes:

```
s = "some string"
```

If you want to use double quotes within a string you need to escape them by doubling them:

```
s = "some ""quoted"" string"
```

Also, you don't need `cmd.exe` for starting an executable via `Run`, but you do need whitespace between the parameters to the executable.

Change this:

```
cmdl.Run "cmd.exe ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe""--app="https://app.powerbi.com/"""--kiosk""--fullscreen""--user-data-dir=c:/monitor1""
```

into this:

```
cmdl.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"" --app=https://app.powerbi.com/ --kiosk --fullscreen --user-data-dir=c:/monitor1"
```

Answer (score 1):

The rule is: Use "" to insert " in VBScript literals.

The first violation in your

```
"cmd.exe ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe""--app="https://app.powerbi.com/"""--kiosk""--fullscreen""--user-data-dir=c:/monitor1""
```

is

```
--app="https
```

This

```
"cmd.exe ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"" --app=""https://app.powerbi.com/"" --kiosk --fullscreen --user-data-dir=""c:/monitor1"""
```

may be what you want.

A better (scaling) approach is to use a quote function and an array for the parts/arguments:

```
Function qq(s)
  qq = """" & s & """"
End Function

s = Join(Array( _
      "cmd.exe" _
    , qq("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe") _
    , "--app=" & qq("https://app.powerbi.com/") _
    , "--kiosk" _
    , "--fullscreen" _
    , "--user-data-dir=" & qq("c:/monitor1") _
), " ")
WScript.Echo s
```

output:

```
cscript a.vbs
cmd.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="https://app.powerbi.com/" --kiosk
 --fullscreen --user-data-dir="c:/monitor1"
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based from ***@Ekkehard.Horner***

So, i liked his method when using the join function with the array.

And, i tried it on my **windows 7 (32 bits)** and it works like a charme ;)

```
Function qq(s)
  qq = chr(34) & s & chr(34)
End Function

s = Join(Array( _
      "cmd /c  start chrome" _
    , "--app=" & qq("https://app.powerbi.com/") _
    , "--kiosk" _
    , "--fullscreen" _
    , "--user-data-dir=" & qq("c:/monitor1") _
), " ")
WScript.Echo s
set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
ws.run s,0,false
```